# How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, files

How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?

How do I assign this to a bash variable so I can use it later?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920333/how-to-check-size-of-a-file LOL for the migrate :-)

Comment: Pair this with `pv` and `cat` for a copy command that shows progress and ETA :)

Comment: stat -c %s file.name

Comment: In case of (very narrow) XY problem, this is neat: if all you need is to test the file has a nonzero size, bash has a conditional expression `-s`, so you may simply test if a file has nonzero length with `if [ -s file ]; then echo "file has nonzero size" ; fi`

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Your best bet if on a GNU system:

```
stat --printf="%s" file.any
```

From [man stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat):

> %s total size, in bytes

In a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=/home/heiko/dummy/packages.txt
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
echo "Size of $FILENAME = $FILESIZE bytes."
```

NOTE: see [@chbrown's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185039/9071) for how to use `stat` on BSD or macOS systems.

Comment: @haunted85 `stat` is the most straightforward way, assuming you're using Linux or Cygwin (`stat` isn't standard). `wc -c` as [suggested by Eugéne](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-do-i-can-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script/16668#16668) is portable.

Comment: `stat: illegal option -- c`

Comment: `stat --printf="%s" file.txt` doesn't output anything on Debian Jessie...

Comment: On MacOS this works: `stat -f%z myfile.tar`

Comment: @woohoo Your prompt overwrites the output. `man stat` says that --printf omits the trailing newline. Use `--format` or `-c` to see the output. Gain more insight by comparing `stat --printf="%s" file.any | xxd -` to `stat -c "%s" file.any | xxd -`

Comment: You can also install the GNU version of stat on Mac with `brew install coreutils` and then run `gstat --printf="%s" file.any` (take note of the g)

Comment: Under BSD (thus including macOS), use `stat -f %z <file>`.

Answer (score 141):

```
file_size_kb=`du -k "$filename" | cut -f1`
```

The problem with using `stat` is that it is a GNU (Linux) extension.  [`du -k`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) and [`cut -f1`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) are specified by POSIX and are therefore portable to any Unix system.

Solaris, for example, ships with bash but not with `stat`.  So this is not entirely hypothetical.

`ls` has a similar problem in that the exact format of the output is not specified, so parsing its output cannot be done portably.  `du -h` is also a GNU extension.

Stick to portable constructs where possible, and you will make somebody's life easier in the future.  Maybe your own.

Comment: `du` doesn't give the size of the file, it gives an indication of how much space the file uses, which is subtly different (usually the size reported by `du` is the size of the file rounded up to the nearest number of blocks, where a block is typically 512B or 1kB or 4kB).

Comment: @Gilles, sparse files (i.e., ones with holes in them) report less than the length.

Comment: This, with `--bytes` or `-b` instead of `-k`, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The **`-h` ("human") option of `du`** will produce the most appropriate answer for general cases: ```file_size=`du -h "$filename" | cut -f1``` , as it will display K (kilobytes), M (Megabytes) or G (Gigabytes) as appropriate.

Comment: @fralau: The OP wants to "assign this to a bash variable so they can use it later", so it is much more likely they want an actual numeric value, not a human-readable  approximation. Also, `-h` is a GNU extension; it is not [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html)

Comment: Using du with `--apparent-size` flag **will return a more precise size** (as stated on man : `print  apparent  sizes,  rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it
       may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks,  and  the
       like`)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - `--bytes` is unfortunately not available on BSD Unix (e.g. macos).  Important since this answer is talking about POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score 101):

You could also use the "word count" command (`wc`):

```
wc -c "$filename" | awk '{print $1}'
```

The problem with `wc` is that it'll add the filename and indent the output.  For example:

```
$ wc -c somefile.txt
    1160 somefile.txt
```

If you would like to avoid chaining a full interpreted language or stream editor just to get a file size count, just redirect the input from the file so that `wc` never sees the filename:

```
wc -c < "$filename"
```

This last form can be used with command substitution to easily grab the value you were seeking as a shell variable, as mentioned by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) below.

```
size="$(wc -c <"$filename")"
```

Comment: `wc -c <"$FILENAME"` gives the size with no other cruft, thus `size=$(wc -c <"$FILENAME")`.

Comment: I've had problems with using `<` and `wc`. Correct file sizes are only guaranteed when using a filename argument.

Comment: Just one more point: I just tested it and `wc -c < file` seems to be very fast, at least on OS X. I'm guessing that wc has the brains to try to stat the file if only -c is specified.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: GNU `wc -c` uses `fstat`, but then seeks to second-last block of the file and reads the last up-to `st_blksize` bytes.  Apparently [this is because files in Linux's `/proc` and `/sys` for example have stat sizes that are only approximate](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c#n246), and `wc` wants to report the actual size, not the stat-reported size.  I guess it would be weird for `wc -c` to report a different size than `wc`, but it's not idea to read data from the file if it's a normal disk file, and it's not in memory.  Or worse, near-line tape storage...

Comment: Interesting. Especially since I'm not sure I'd trust the pseudo-files in /proc and /sys to handle seek() properly.

Comment: It seems like `printf` still sees the indentation, e.g. `printf "Size: $size"` -> `size: <4 spaces> 54339`. On the other hand `echo` ignores the whitespace. Any way to make it consistent?

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov yes…

Use `printf "Size: %s\n" ${size}` and it should generate the expected result...

Comment: In Mb (Format: 0.00 MB) : $(wc -c "myfile.txt" | awk 'BEGIN{ OFMT="%.2f" } END {print $1/1024/1024}')

Comment: Late comment...   If the command is given as `wc -c < file` would `wc` know which file it's been given? I mean, it seems a little too clever to me. If it were `wc -c file` I could understand, but not with '<'.  I'm not asking if it *could* be done, only if it's always going to return what the person at the keyboard intended.

Comment: @keithpjolley: `wc` won't (or, at least, shouldn't), but the shell will...

Comment: I guess the question is how can `wc` be clever about a file if its input is `<`?

Comment: @keithpjolley: By calling `fstat`. Try running `strace wc -c </etc/passwd` and you can see what it is doing.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. It uses the file descriptor, not the filename.

Answer (score 75):

BSD's (macOS's) `stat` has a different format argument flag, and different field specifiers. From `man stat(1)`:

- `-f format`: Display information using the specified format. See the FORMATS section for a description of valid formats.
- ... the FORMATS section ...
- `z`: The size of file in bytes.

So all together now:

```
stat -f%z myfile1.txt
```

NOTE: see [@b01's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16644/50950) for how to use the `stat` command on GNU/Linux systems. :)

Comment: Note that this is a BSD-only solution. It doesn't work with GNU `stat`, unfortunately.

Comment: stat --version==8.30: `stat -c%s <file>`

Answer (score 49):

Depends what you mean by *size*.

```
size=$(wc -c < "$file")
```

will give you the number of bytes that can be read from the file. IOW, it's the size of the contents of the file. It will however read the contents of the file (except if the file is a regular file or symlink to regular file in most `wc` implementations as an optimisation). That may have side effects. For instance, for a named pipe, what has been read can no longer be read again and for things like `/dev/zero` or `/dev/random` which are of infinite size, it's going to take a while. That also means you need `read` permission to the file, and the *last access timestamp* of the file may be updated.

That's standard and portable, however note that some `wc` implementations may include leading blanks in that output. One way to get rid of them is to use:

```
size=$(($(wc -c < "$file")))
```

or to avoid an error about an empty arithmetic expression in `dash` or `yash` when `wc` produces no  output (like when the file can't be opened):

```
size=$(($(wc -c < "$file") +0))
```

`ksh93` has `wc` builtin (provided  you enable it, you can also invoke it as `command /opt/ast/bin/wc`) which makes it the most efficient for regular files in that shell.

Various systems have a command called `stat` that's an interface to the `stat()` or `lstat()` system calls.

Those report information found in the inode. One of that information is the `st_size` attribute. For regular files, that's the size of the content (how much data could be read from it in the absence of error (that's what most `wc -c` implementations use in their optimisation)). For symlinks, that's the size in bytes of the target path. For named pipes, depending on the system, it's either 0 or the number of bytes currently in the pipe buffer. Same for block devices where depending on the system, you get 0 or the size in bytes of the underlying storage.

You don't need read permission to the file to get that information, only search permission to the directory it is linked to.

By chronological¹ order, there is:

- [IRIX `stat`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/stat.1.html) (90's):

  ```
  stat -qLs -- "$file"
  ```

  returns the `st_size` attribute of `$file` (`lstat()`) or:

  ```
  stat -s -- "$file"
  ```

  same except when `$file` is a symlink in which case it's the `st_size` of the file after symlink resolution.
- [`zsh` `stat` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fstat-Module) (now also known as `zstat`) in the `zsh/stat` module (loaded with `zmodload zsh/stat`) (1997):

  ```
  stat -L +size -- $file # st_size of file
  stat +size -- $file    # after symlink resolution
  ```

  or to store in a variable:

  ```
  stat -L -A size +size -- $file
  ```

  obviously, that's the most efficient in that shell.
- [GNU `stat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) (2001); also in BusyBox `stat` since 2005 and Toybox `stat` since 2013 (both copying the GNU `stat` interface):

  ```
  stat -c %s -- "$file"  # st_size of file
  stat -Lc %s -- "$file" # after symlink resolution
  ```

  (note the meaning of `-L` is reversed compared to IRIX or `zsh` `stat`).
- [BSDs `stat`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1) (2002):

  ```
  stat -f %z -- "$file"  # st_size of file
  stat -Lf %z -- "$file" # after symlink resolution
  ```

Or you can use the `stat()`/`lstat()` function of some scripting language like `perl`:

```
perl -le 'print((lstat shift)[7])' -- "$file"
```

AIX also has an [`istat` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) which will dump all the `stat()` (not `lstat()`, so won't work on symlinks) information and which you could post-process with, for example:

```
LC_ALL=C istat "$file" | awk 'NR == 4 {print $5}'
```

(thanks @JeffSchaller for the [help figuring out the details](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48172)).

In `tcsh`:

```
@ size = -Z $file:q
```

(size after symlink resolution)

Long before GNU introduced its `stat` command, the same could be achieved with GNU `find` command with its `-printf` predicate (already in 1991):

```
find -- "$file" -prune -printf '%s\n'    # st_size of file
find -L -- "$file" -prune -printf '%s\n' # after symlink resolution
```

One issue though is that doesn't work if `$file` starts with `-` or is a `find` predicate (like `!`, `(`...).

Since version 4.9, that can be worked around by passing the file path through its stdin rather than as an argument with:

```
printf '%s\0' "$file" |
  find -files0-from - -prune -printf '%s\n'
```

The standard command to get the `stat()`/`lstat()` information is `ls`.

POSIXly, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -dln -- "$file" | awk '{print $5; exit}'
```

(`-n` is required to imply `-l` so the latter should not be necessary, but you'll find that on some BSDs, it is).

and add `-L` for the same after symlink resolution. That doesn't work for device files though where the 5<sup>th</sup> field is the device major number instead of the size.

For block devices, systems where `stat()` returns 0 for `st_size`, usually have other APIs to report the size of the block device. For instance, Linux has the `BLKGETSIZE64` `ioctl()`, and most Linux distributions now ship with a `blockdev` command that can make use of it:

```
blockdev --getsize64 -- "$device_file"
```

However, you need read permission to the device file for that. It's usually possible to derive the size by other means. For instance (still on Linux):

```
lsblk -bdno size -- "$device_file"
```

Should work except for empty devices.

An approach that works for all *seekable* files (so includes regular files, most block devices and some character devices) is to open the file and seek to the end:

- With `zsh` (after loading the `zsh/system` module):

  ```
  {sysseek -w end 0 && size=$((systell(0)))} < $file
  ```
- With `ksh93`:

  ```
  < "$file" <#((size=EOF))
  ```

  or

  ```
  { size=$(<#((EOF))); } < "$file"
  ```
- with `perl`:

  ```
  perl -le 'seek STDIN, 0, 2 or die "seek: $!"; print tell STDIN' < "$file"
  ```

For named pipes, we've seen that some systems (AIX, Solaris, HP/UX at least) make the amount of data in the pipe buffer available in `stat()`'s `st_size`. Some (like Linux or FreeBSD) don't.

On Linux at least, you can use the `FIONREAD` `ioctl()` after having opened the pipe (in read+write mode to avoid it hanging):

```
fuser -s -- "$fifo_file" && 
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
            ioctl(STDIN, &FIONREAD, $n) or die$!;
            print unpack "L", $n' <> "$fifo_file"
```

However note that while it doesn't *read* the content of the pipe, the mere opening of the named pipe here can still have side effects. We're using `fuser` to check first that some process already has the pipe open to alleviate that but that's not foolproof as `fuser` may not be able to check all processes.

Now, so far we've only been considering the size of the *primary* data associated with the files. That doesn't take into account the size of the metadata and all the supporting infrastructure needed to store that file.

Another inode attribute returned by `stat()` is `st_blocks`. That's the number of 512 byte ([1024 on HP/UX](/q/669543)) blocks that is used to store the file's data (and sometimes some of its metadata like the extended attributes on ext4 filesystems on Linux). That doesn't include the inode itself, or the entries in the directories the file is linked to.

Size and disk usage are not necessarily tightly related as compression, sparseness (sometimes some metadata), extra infrastructure like indirect blocks in some filesystems have an influence on the latter.

That's typically what `du` uses to report disk usage. Most of the commands listed above will be able to get you that information.

- `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ls -sd -- "$file" | awk '{print $1; exit}'`
- `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 du -s -- "$file"` (not for directories where that would include the disk usage of the files within).
- GNU `find -- "$file" -printf '%b\n'`
- `zstat -L +block -- $file`
- GNU `stat -c %b -- "$file"`
- BSD `stat -f %b -- "$file"`
- `perl -le 'print((lstat shift)[12])' -- "$file"`

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, early versions of UNIX in the 70s, from v1 to v4 had a `stat` command. It was just dumping information from the inode and didn't take options. It apparently disappeared in v5 (1974) presumably because it was redundant with `ls -l`.</sup>

Comment: clearly the most comprehensive and informational answer. thank you. i can use this to create cross platform bash scripts using the BSD and GNU stats info

Comment: Fun fact: GNU coreutils `wc -c` uses `fstat`, but then reads the last up-to `st_blksize` bytes.  Apparently [this is because files in Linux's `/proc` and `/sys` for example have stat sizes that are only approximate](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c#n246).  This is good for correctness, but bad if the end of the file is on disk and not in memory (esp. if used on many files in a loop).  And very bad if the file is migrated to [near-line tape storage](http://www.linux.org/threads/dmapi-data-management-api.4317/), or e.g. a FUSE transparent-decompression filesystem.

Comment: wouldnt this work too `ls -go file | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: @StevenPenny those `-go` would be the SysV ones, they wouldn't work on BSDs (optional (XSI) in POSIX). You'd also need `ls -god file | awk '{print $3; exit}'` (`-d` for it to work on directories, `exit` for symlinks with newlines in the target). The problems with device files also remain.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do `wc -c <binary_file` can return the size of a binary file correctly in bytes?I read in [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815582/4023950) that it works, but can you please also confirm. thank you

Comment: @αғsнιη the Unix API makes no distinction between text and binary files. It's all sequences of bytes. Some applications may want to interpret those bytes as text but obviously not `wc -c` which reports the number of bytes.

Comment: @haunted85, I've rejected your edit. `wc -c < file` in most `wc` implementations will not read the contents of `file` if its regular but do `fstat()` (and `lseek()` to retrieve the initial position in the file) to determine its size. You can run `strace wc -c < file` or the equivalent command on your system to check.

Answer (score 24):

This script combines many ways to calculate the file size:

```
(
  du --apparent-size --block-size=1 "$file" 2>/dev/null ||
  gdu --apparent-size --block-size=1 "$file" 2>/dev/null ||
  find "$file" -printf "%s" 2>/dev/null ||
  gfind "$file" -printf "%s" 2>/dev/null ||
  stat --printf="%s" "$file" 2>/dev/null ||
  stat -f%z "$file" 2>/dev/null ||
  wc -c <"$file" 2>/dev/null
) | awk '{print $1}'
```

The script works on many Unix systems including Linux, BSD, OSX, Solaris, SunOS, etc.

The file size shows the number of bytes. It is the apparent size, which is the bytes the file uses on a typical disk, without special compression, or special sparse areas, or unallocated blocks, etc.

This script has a production version with more help and more options here:
https://github.com/SixArm/file-size

Answer (score 12):

*stat* appears to do this with the fewest system calls:

```
$ set debian-live-8.2.0-amd64-xfce-desktop.iso

$ strace stat --format %s $1 | wc
    282    2795   27364

$ strace wc --bytes $1 | wc
    307    3063   29091

$ strace du --bytes $1 | wc
    437    4376   41955

$ strace find $1 -printf %s | wc
    604    6061   64793
```

Answer (score 8):

`ls -l filename` will give you lots of information about a file, including its file size, permissions and owner.

The file size in the fifth column, and is displayed in bytes. In the example below, the filesize is just under 2KB:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user owner 1985 2011-07-12 16:48 index.php
```

**Edit:** This is apparently not as reliable as the `stat` command.

Comment: I think both `ls -l` and `stat` command give reliable size information. I did not find any reference to the contrary. `ls -s` will give size in number of blocks.

Comment: @dabest1 it's not reliable in a sense that in another unix, their output can be different (and in some unixes it is).

Comment: Yes, IIRC, Solaris didn't display the group name by default, leading to fewer columns in the output.

Comment: Since the size is pure numeric, surrounded by whitespace, and the date year is pure numeric, in a defined format, it would be possible to use a regexp to treat user+owner as one field, whether or not the group was present. (an exercise for the reader !)

Answer (score 8):

`du filename` will tell you disk usage in bytes.

I prefer `du -h filename`, which gives you the size in a human readable format.

Comment: that or `stat -c "%s"` ;)

Comment: This flavor of `du` prints out size in blocks of 1024 bytes, not a simple count of bytes.

Comment: Note that standard `du` give an output in number of 512-byte units. GNU `du` uses kibibytes instead unless called with `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in its environment.

Comment: For files of type _directory_, that gives the disk usage of the directory but also of all the other files within (recursively).

Answer (score 5):

Create small utility functions in your shell scripts that you can delegate to.

*Example*

```
#! /bin/sh -
# vim: set ft=sh

# size utility that works on GNU and BSD systems
size(){
    case $(uname) in
        (Darwin | *BSD*)
            stat -Lf %z -- "$1";;
        (*) stat -c %s -- "$1"
    esac
}

for f do
    printf '%s\n' "$f : $(gzip < "$f" | wc -c) bytes (versus $(size "$f") bytes)"
done
```

Based on info from @Stéphane Chazelas' answer.

Comment: See also `gzip -v < file > /dev/null` to check the compressibility of a file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas not sure if i think it was an improvement. those case statements can easily put noobs off; I certainly never remember how to get them right :-) are case statements inherently more portable since you did it? i see the point when there are more than two cases, but otherwise ...+

Comment: I suppose it's also a matter of taste, but here it's the typical case where you'd want to use a `case` statement. `case` is the Bourne/POSIX construct to do pattern matching. `[[...]]` is ksh/bash/zsh only (with variations).

Answer (score 4):

I found an AWK 1 liner, and it had a bug but I fixed it. I also added in PetaBytes after TeraBytes.

```
FILE_SIZE=234234 # FILESIZE IN BYTES
FILE_SIZE=$(echo "${FILE_SIZE}" | awk '{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s", $1, v[s] }')
```

Considering **stat** is not on every single system, you can almost always use the AWK solution. Example; the Raspberry Pi does not have **stat** but it does have **awk**.

Comment: Completely NOT what the OP asked, but nice little piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and simplest (IMO) method is:

```
bash_var=$(stat -c %s /path/to/filename)
```

Comment: Then upvote one or more of the existing answers that mention stat; no need to repeat it again...

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just upvoted Stephane's answer on your instructions. I think it is too complicated for my purposes. Which is why I posted this simple answer for like minded souls.

Comment: Thank you; it's just that a *sixth* instance of a "stat" answer doesn't simplify this Q & A, but would rather make a new reader ask themselves "how is this answer different from the other ones?" and lead to more confusion instead of less.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I guess. But I could complain about the many `du` and `wc` answers that should have a disclaimer *NEVER DO THIS* in real life. I just used my answer in a real life application tonight and thought it was worthwhile sharing. I guess we all have our opinions *shrugs*.

Answer (score -1):

I like the wc option myself. Paired with 'bc,' you can get decimals to as many places as you please.

I was looking to improve a script I had that awk'ed out the 'file size' column of an 'ls -alh' command. I didn't want just integer file sizes, and two decimals seemed to suit, so after reading this discussion, I came up with the code below.

I suggest breaking the line at the semicolons if you include this in a script.

`file=$1; string=$(wc -c $file); bite=${string% *}; okay=$(echo "scale=2; $bite/1024" | bc);friend=$(echo -e "$file $okay" "kb"); echo -e "$friend"`

My script is called **gpfl**, for "get picture file length." I use it after doing a *mogrify* on a file in imagemagick, before opening or re-loading a picture in a GUI jpeg  viewer.

I don't know how this rates as an "answer," as it borrows much from what's already been offered and discussed. So I'll leave it there.

**BZT**

Comment: I would prefer using "stat" or "ls". Typically I don't like using "wc" to get file sizes because it physically reads the entire file. If you have a lot of files, or particularly large files, this can take a lot of time. But your solution is creative...+1.

Comment: I agree with notion of using "stat" over "wc" for filesize, however if you use "wc -c", no data will be read; instead lseek will be used to figure out the number of bytes in a file. http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/wc.c#228

Comment: @bbaja42: note that GNU Coreutils `wc` does read the last block of the file, in case `stat.st_size` was only an approximation (like for Linux `/proc` and `/sys` files).  I guess they decided not to make the main comment more complicated when they added that logic a couple lines down: http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/wc.c#246