# Shell scripts Linux -> Solaris conversion guide

Tags: bash, shell, solaris, standard

I've developed a few Bash scripts on a [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) system which should now be made to work on a minimal installation of Sun Solaris 10. Is there a guide somewhere with at least some **general tips** for conversion, and even better, a "**conversion table**" for common commands and options? [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-do-i-can-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script/16645#16645) would be a good example of a single entry in such a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the web for "sun application porting assistant 1.0 final release". I believe it is still downloadable from Oracle web site:

*It is a static source code analysis and code scanning tool that can be used to identify incompatible APIs between the Linux and Solaris platforms. Sun Application Porting Assistant's robust C/C++ and shell script parsers are able to examine these source files with reasonable accuracy and produce reports that can be used in porting the application. Together with an easy-to-use GUI and a simple command-line interface, Sun APA is intended to simplify and speed up estimation and porting times.*

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing we need! It is very low on detail, however - The "Issue Detail" view is empty even though several issues are reported...

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Resources for portable shell programming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming).

For Solaris specifically, the biggest gotcha is to make sure you have `/usr/xpg4/bin` or `/usr/xpg6/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`. The utilities in `/usr/bin` are backwards compatible with the pre-POSIX era. The utilities in `/usr/xpg4*` are compatible with Single Unix ([v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/) and [v3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) respectively). IIRC there are a few shell built-ins that change their behavior depending on the `PATH` too.

If your scripts are using bash constructs, you'll have to adapt them to run under ksh instead. Bash and ksh have a large common subset that contains many useful features that aren't in POSIX (arrays, extended glob patterns, `[[ … ]]`, `<(…)`, …). You can run ksh on Linux too; most distributions have it as an optional package, and you can download the source [from the official site](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/), or from [more usable places](ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/ksh/).
[The LFS site has installation instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/ksh.html).

Comment: Thanks. Bash is installed, so we won't have to port to a different language.

Answer (score 2):

The [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) website has a table showing equivalents for common commands across many different *nix flavors, though more focused on users & admins than shell script writers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing what will work and what won't then just a install a Solaris on your workstation and test it out. (you obviously need a hypervisor to do that - recommend VirtualBox as you can download pre-build images for Solaris for use with VirtualBox). Won't cost you a penny and takes around 30 mins to install. Most of that is download time.