# Script to compare the "file size" with "last name of file" and if unmatched delete the file

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames, size

In my environment, we'll be receiving files from clients into our Sftp server. Sftp processes the files, and moves it to another tool, by appending the file size at the end of the file name. For example, `samplefile.20150706` of size 1024 would be created as `samplefile.20150706.1024`.

If file size and name (the last part after `.`) matches, our tool will pick the file and send it to ETL. If the file stays in that place for more than an hour (not processed due to unmatched size and name), the tool will send us alerts, as files are over an one hour old.

I'm looking for commands, which will extract the last part of the file name and compare it with file size, and eventually delete the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Get the file size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16644/3645):

```
size="$(stat --printf="%s" "$path")"
```

[Get the path without the last extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash):

```
path_without_extension="${path%.*}"
```

Compare the two:

```
[ "${path_without_extension}.${size}" = "$path" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

`ls -l | awk '{print $5}'` gives your file size
`echo file_name | awk -F"." '{print $3}'`  gives you file size extracted from name.

`` a=`ls -l | awk '{print $5}'`
b=`echo file_name | awk -F"." '{print $3}'`
if [ $a -eq $b ]
then
     echo "you can do your processing here"
fi ``

Comment: another way to get file size:

du -k file_name | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: -1 [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) arguments to `[`, and [use `$()` for command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).