# LS absolute path returns no such file

Tags: linux, shell, cron, raspberry-pi

I am running a bash script as a `cron` job. The thing is that I use `ls` in the script and it says that absolute path file doesn't exist. But it exists:

```
function get_curr_video_size()
{

    curr_size=`ls -l ${video_name} | awk '{print $5}'`
    echo ${curr_size}

}
curr_size=`get_curr_video_size`
```

`${video_name}` is get by another function at earlier point, so it can't be non-existent during `get_curr_video_size` call.

Error is:

```
    ls: cannot access /home/pi/draft_videos/03_04_2017/test_03_04_2017_22:05:19.mp4: No such 
file or directory`
```

But the file exists. When I `ls` it in terminal it is there:

```
ls -l /home/pi/draft_videos/03_04_2017/test_03_04_2017_22:05:19.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Apr  3 22:05 /home/pi/draft_videos/03_04_2017/test_03_04_2017_22:05:19.mp4
```

If I run my script in a terminal instead as a `cron` job, it is ok. Seems like `cron` messes up things somehow, but I can't understand why.

I am using Raspbian Jessie on RPI.

Comment: Is that the real filename or are there actually spaces in the name?

Comment: @thrig this is the real file name, I don't think there are whitespaces in it, I copied it directly from the message in terminal and it was found

Comment: Please include your `cron` definition

Comment: @roaima well, its kinda complicated, because my `cron` job actually runs a pyhon script, which using `subprocess` is starting the script I described.

Comment: Is there any possibility whatsoever that you could have two instances of the script running with the same filename at the same time?

Comment: In shell, to get the size of a file, try [`stat -c '%s' FILENAME`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/coreutils/stat.1.en.html) or [`du` or `wc -c`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script). In Python, use [`os.stat`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python). Not an answer to what's happening, just a pointer to a much better way to accomplish your goal

Comment: What if you simplify the whole thing with `curr_size=$(stat -c %s "$video_name")`? Notice that when a variable is used it's used in double quotes, and backticks have been replaced by the modern `$(...)` construct.

Comment: I am gonna try the suggested ways of getting the file size

Comment: Also: What kind of system is this running on (personal workstation? Big institution set up?). Is the cron job out of your personal crontab, or a system one? And as a troubleshooting step, does installing a cron job that *just* does the `ls -l` work?

Comment: @derobert It is run on my personal Raspberry Pi system. Yes, I tried a cron job with only `ls -l` and it worked. Hmmm, maybe I am missing something. I'll try to investigate more and will let you know guys, Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @CuriousGuy The fact that it's your personal RPi seems to rule out anything complicated (e.g., different filesystem namespaces or some sort of access control system) going on. Most likely, it's simply that the path doesn't exist. E.g., because there is some weird character in the middle of it.

Comment: Wow, guys, it really doesn't exist. I did a `ls` of the directory and it is empty at the time of the `ls -l ${video_name}`.